# Finding unsatisfied bundle constraints from Karaf console

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

How can I find unsatisfied constraints of a bundle which didn't start from Apache Karaf console? I.e. what is its equivalent of Equinox's `diag` command?

Comment: Does it have to be from the console? Have you considered using [Felix's Web Console](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Karaf are you using?  The following should be relevant to Karaf 2.x

Annoyingly the package:imports/package:exports commands only work on a bundle in the STARTED state.

If the bundle is only INSTALLED you can use:  `headers ${BUNDLE NUMBER}`  will highlight any missing imports in red.

Also trying to start a bundle should print to the console any unresolved constraints as an LDAP filter expression.